# Azure Monitor: Query for disabled functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

Is there a clean way to query for the names for all disabled functions in Azure Monitor?

Sure, I can hard-code the names or the functions and check if there has been any logs for the functions, but I imagine there is a smarter way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Application insights for Azure function. For details, please follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#add-to-an-existing-function-app). Then you can use the query below to get all the disabled function names.

Note: The query below can be run in Application insights, or Azure Monitor.

```
traces 
//use sdkVersion to ensure it's an anzure function
| where sdkVersion contains "azurefunctions" 
//then check if the message contains the word disabled
| where  message contains "disabled" 
//get the function name from message
| extend functionname=substring(message, 10,indexof(message,"'", 10)-10)
```

Explain about the query:

1.if the function is disabled, then the message field should contain the information like "function xxx is disabled."

2.to ensure it's an azure function, I check the field sdkVersion to see if it contains word "azurefunctions"

3.at last, fetch the function name from the message field.

The test result:

[image]

I tested it with function v3, if you're using azure function v2 or v1, you may(or may not) modify the query a little, but it should be easy.